# `data.table` way to select subsets based on `agrep`?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to convert from `data.frame` to `data.table`, and need some advice on some logical indexing I am trying to do on a single column. Here is a table I have:

```
places <- data.table(name=c('Brisbane', 'Sydney', 'Auckland',
                            'New Zealand', 'Australia'),
                     search=c('Brisbane AU Australia',
                              'Sydney AU Australia',
                              'Auckland NZ New Zealand',
                              'NZ New Zealand',
                              'AU Australia'))

#           name                  search
# 1:    Brisbane   Brisbane AU Australia
# 2:      Sydney     Sydney AU Australia
# 3:    Auckland Auckland NZ New Zealand
# 4: New Zealand          NZ New Zealand  
# 5:   Australia            AU Australia

setkey(places, search)
```

I want to extract rows whose `search` column matches all words in a list, like so:

```
words <- c('AU', 'Brisbane')
hits <- places
for (w in words) {
    hits <- hits[search %like% w]
}
# I end up with the 'Brisbane AU Australia' row.
```

I have one question:

Is there a more `data.table`-way to do this? It seems to me that storing `hits` each time seems like a `data.frame` way to do this.

This is subject to the caveat that I eventually want to use `agrep` rather than `grep`/`%like%`:

```
words <- c('AU', 'Bisbane') # note the mis-spelling
hits <- places
for (w in words) {
    hits <- hits[agrep(w, search)]
}
```

I feel like this doesn't quite take advantage of `data.table`'s capabilities and would appreciate thoughts on how to modify the code so it does.

---

**EDIT**
I want the for loop because `places` is quite large, and I only want to find rows that match *all* the words. Hence I only need to search in the results for the last word for the next word (that is, successively refine the results).

With the talk of "binary scan" vs "vector scan" in the `data.table` introduction (i.e. "bad way" is `DT[DT$x == "R" & DT$y == "h"]`, "good way" is `setkey(DT, x, y); DT[J("R", "h")]` I just wondered if there was some way I could apply this approach here.

Comment: Not sure if this is the intended use of your for-loop. Why are you overwriting hits? Wouldn't this just result in the last subset? And I don't think there's much to harness from the power of `data.table` from this problem, at least to my knowledge.

Comment: I do want the loop, updated the question with explanation.

Comment: mathematical.coffee, I see what you mean to do now. But, they are two keys there (for two *different* columns). Your problem is that  the subsetting operation depends on `agrep`. That means, you can't directly subset by a value of key column, which renders `data.table` not that useful, iiuc (unless you can subset using partial matches of key column entries, which isn't possible at least as of now). If this is unclear, I'll write an answer in the morning explaining this comment better.

Comment: Ahh, this makes sense to me. Write it up when you get the time and I'll accept it. cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematical.coffee, as I mentioned under comments, you can not "partial match" by setting a column (or more columns) as key column(s). That is, in the `data.table` places, you've set the column "search" as the *key column*. Here, you can *fast subset* by using `data.table's` binary search (as opposed to vector scan subsetting) by doing:

```
places["Brisbane AU Australia"] # binary search when "search" column is key'd
# is faster compared to:

places[search == "Brisbane AU Australia"] # vector scan
```

But in your case, yo require:

```
places["AU"]
```

to give all rows with has a partial match of "AU" within the key column. And this is not possible (while it's certainly a very interesting feature to have).

---

If the `substring` you're searching for by itself *does not contain mismatches*, then you can try splitting the search strings into separate columns. That is, the column `search` if split into three columns containing `Brisbane`, `AU` and `Australia`, then you can set the *key* of the `data.table` to the columns that contain `AU` and `Brisbane`. Then, you can query the way you mention as:

```
# fast subset, AU and Brisbane are entries of the two key columns
places[J("AU", "Brisbane")]
```

Comment: +1 [Fuzzy matching](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=2044) is on the feature request list.

Comment: cheers (unfortunately my `search` column will have a variable, theoretically unlimited number of words). I will keep with my current code.

Answer (score 0):

You can vectorize the `agrep` function to avoid looping.

Note that the result of `agrep2` is a list hence the `unlist` call

```
words <- c("Bisbane", "NZ")
agrep2 <- Vectorize(agrep, vectorize.args = "pattern")
places[unlist(agrep2(words, search))]

##           name                  search
## 1:    Brisbane   Brisbane AU Australia
## 2:    Auckland Auckland NZ New Zealand
## 3: New Zealand          NZ New Zealand
```